# empty array is returned even after pushing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have declared an empty array called **`answerDataArray`** and pushed values into the array (values are snapshots from firebase DB). When I can use `console.log(answerDataArray)` outside the **`forEach`** loop it showing an empty array but when I do `console.log(answerDataArray)` anywhere inside the `forEach` loop I get the populated array. Please tell what happening here.

```
var ideationContestRef = ideationDataRef.child(contestDataRef.key);
    ideationContestRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.child("answers").exists()){
            snapshot.child("answers").ref.once("value", function(snapAnswerKey){
                var answerKey = Object.keys(snapAnswerKey.val());
                var answerDataRef = db.ref("answerData");
                var answerDataArray = [];
                answerKey.forEach(function(key){
                    answerDataRef.child(key).once("value", function(snapAnswerData){
                        answerDataArray.push(snapAnswerData.val());
                    });
                });
                console.log(answerDataArray);
                // res.render("ideation", {id: contestId, layout: 'styled.handlebars', page: 'ideation', user_logged_in: user_presence, contestData: snapshot.val(), answerDataArray: answerDataArray});
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably is the fact that `answerDataRef.child(key).once("value", function(snapAnswerData){` is **async**, therefore you can't expect to have values line after the forEach that you have mentioned.

Maybe you can use `Promise` in order to return async value.

Comment: could you please show how to do it ?

Comment: You will need to convert the function to be Promise based, you can read here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise